# 2D rotation openGL es 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, matrix, 2d, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to make a game and I need my startship(triangle) to be rotated around its own center. (It should looks like you just put a paper triangle on a table and rotating it)
The coords of my triangle is

```
public float coords[] = {
        0.0f, 0.1f, 0.0f,
        -0.05f, -0.1f, 0.0f,
        0.05f, -0.1f, 0.0f,

        // barrier, ignore this coords
        -0.039f, -0.05f, 0.0f,
        0.039f, -0.05f, 0.0f,
    };
```

The triangle right in the center of axis. Right?
I am trying to rotate it with

```
Matrix.rotateM(rotateMatrix, 0, rotateZ, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

But it looks like this: [image]

And that's not what I wanted. Please, give me an advice what to do to make my triangle rotating looks just like a paper one on a table.
Edit: there is no projection matrix and translate matrix is 0 by x,y and z.

Comment: You may have to define a [camera location](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/projection.html). Otherwise the code you submitted works as expected.

Comment: seems like the key was "ratio" in Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, +ratio, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f, 20f); can anyone explain me why?

Comment: opengl takes the final vertex coordinates in "normalized device coordinates": -1 to 1 in x and y. This ignores the number of pixels in your viewport and hence aspect ratio. The intended use is incorporating the window's aspect ratio into your projection matrix, as you have done.